# Convergent sequences are closed subspace of $l^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Here is the exercise:

Let's consider the Banach space $l^{\infty}$ with the sup norm.

We consider the following subspace of $l^{\infty}$ :

$C = ${ $x \in l^{\infty} : \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n\quad\text{ exists }$}.

We have to show that $C$ is a closed subspace of $l^{\infty}$ and is thus also a Banach space with respect to the sup norm.

Let $y$ denote $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $x_n$.

The key there is to show that every convergent sequence in $C$, say every sequence in $C$ converges within $C$, hence we have to show that $y$ belongs to $C$.
I've successfully shown that $y$ is a Cauchy sequence in $l^{\infty}$, but I don't know what to do with that. When I'm looking at the correction, it says that $\{ y\text{ Cauchy}\} \Rightarrow \{y\text{ convergent}\} \Rightarrow \{y \in C\}$.

That's where I'm lost. I don't understand why we can deduce $y$ is convergent by having shown $y$ is Cauchy. Also, I don't understand why we have to show that $y$ is Cauchy.

I hope someone can explain me those two problems I have.

I do understand though that $C$ being closed implies that $C$ is a Banach space.

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\to 0}x_n$ mean?

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake. I meant $\lim_{n\to \infty}$

Comment: Choose $x^{(k)}\in C$ such that $\|x^{(k)}-y\|_\infty\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ for some $y\in\ell^\infty$. Now prove that $y = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence (and therefore belongs to $C$).

Comment: You can show that the complement is open. Take any bounded sequence that doesn't converge, and find a perturbation such that any sequence in that ball also doesn't converge.

Comment: This is what I've done. By using the fact that $x^{(k)}$ is Cauchy and the convergence of $x^{(k)}$ to $y$, I've shown that $y^{(k)}$ is Cauchy, I don't understand how we can say that $y^{(k)}$ is hence convergent.

Comment: If $y = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^\infty$ is Cauchy then it converges because $\mathbb R$ is complete.

Comment: Oh thank you I got it now ! I'll also try to show that the complement is open. Thank you for all your answers. Can we deduce from that though that every closed space is Banach ?

Comment: Of course not. Each normed space is closed (in itself). But it is true that a closed subspace of a Banach space is Banach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C$ converging to $y=(y_j)_j\in l_{\infty}.$ Let $x_n=(x_{n,j})_j.$  For each $j$ we have  $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n,j}=y_j . $

By contradiction: Suppose $y$ is not a convergent sequence. Then for some $r>0$, we have $\forall n\in N\;(\exists j,k\;(n\leq j<k\land |y_j-y_k|>r).$

But let  $\|x_{n}-y\|<r/4$ and let $j_0$ satisfy $(j\geq j_0\implies |x_{n,j}-L(n)|<r/4),$ where $L(n)=\lim_{j\to \infty}x_{n,j}.$

Then there exists $j\geq j_0$ and $k>j$ such that $|y_j-y_k|>r.$

This yields  $$|y_j-L(n)|\leq |y_j-x_{n,j}|+|x_{n,j}-L(n)| <\|y-x_n\|+r/4<r/2$$ and $$|y_k-L(n)|\leq  |y_k-x_{n.k}|+|x_{n,k}-L(n)|<  \|y-x_n|+r/4<2.$$ But then we have $|y_j-L(n)|<r/2$ and $|y_k-L(n)|<r/2,$ which implies $|y_j-y_k|<r,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}\cup\{\infty\}$ and define a topology on $X$ that is discrete, but neighborhoods of $\infty$ include all large integers. Then $X$ is compact, and your sequences are the same as the continuous functions $C(X)$. This is the one-point compactification. $C(X)$ is a Banach space, and the elements of $C(X)$ are determined by their values on the integers, with a natural isometric inclusion in $\ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: Why the -1 on this solution?

Comment: It's not from me, but it is true I don't understand your answer... What is the link with continuous functions ?

Comment: @AudreyI The continuous functions with sup norm on a compact Hausdorff space is a Banach space. You can view sequences with a limit at $\infty$ as continuous functions on the one point compactification of $\{ 1,2,3,\cdots,\}$. The topology is discrete on the integers, and the neighborhoods of $\infty$ include all large integers. That's a compact topology, and a function is continuous on that space iff it is a sequence with a limit at $\infty$. This space of continuous functions with sup norm is isometrically equivalent to your space of sequences. So it's complete inside $\ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: What a beautiful answer! It may not be to everyone's taste, but for me it's the clearest by far. To make the link to the question more apparent, it might be helpful to say "the subspace $C \subset l^\infty$ is the same as" instead of "your sequences are the same as."

Answer (score -1):

Consider $l^{\infty}\setminus C$
Let $y_{n} \in l^{\infty}\setminus C\,,$ then $\forall y \in\mathbb{R}, \exists \varepsilon_{y} > 0$ such that $\|y-y_{n}\|_{\infty} > 2\varepsilon_{y}$
Now consider $\mathbb{B}(y_{n},\varepsilon_{y})$
Let $z_{n} \in \mathbb{B}(y_{n},\varepsilon_{y})\Longrightarrow \|y_{n}-z_{n}\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon_{y}$
So $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$;
$\|y-z_{n}\|_{\infty} = \|y-y_{n}-(z_{n}-y_{n})\|_{\infty} \geq \|y-y_{n}\|_{\infty} - \|z-y_{n}\|_{\infty} > 2\varepsilon_{y} - \varepsilon_{y} = \varepsilon_{y} > 0$
$\Longrightarrow \mathbb{B}(y_{n},\varepsilon_{y}) \subseteq l^{\infty}\setminus C\Longrightarrow l^{\infty}\setminus C$ is open $\Longrightarrow C$ is closed.